# How to have dynamic number of databases with ormlite

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm using Ormlite has my database for my android application.  I have now been given requirements to create a container to be able to hold multiple databases.  I do not know before hand how many databases I will need as the number of databases by the container will be dynamic.  I've reviewed ormlite's multiple database code, but that is if you know how many databases you have before hand and you create one class per database.  I don't have that information available to me.  So the question is, how can I create a DatabaseHelper class with ormlite to handle multiple different databases and still be thread safe?  All the databases hold the exact same type of data, just different data per container.

DatabaseHelper code:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
    private static final int    DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private Dao<MyData, Integer> myDataDao;
    private static final AtomicInteger usageCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private volatile static DatabaseHelper helper = null;
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String dynamicDBName)
    {
        super(context, dynamicDBName, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public static DatabaseHelper getHelper(Context context, String dynamicDBName)
    {
        if (helper == null)
        {
            synchronized (DatabaseHelper.class)
            {
                // double check lock to prevent method from being synchronized
                // requiring sync lock only being used once
                if (helper == null)
                    helper = new DatabaseHelper(context, dynamicDBName);
            }

        }
        usageCounter.incrementAndGet();
        return helper;
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
    {
        if (usageCounter.decrementAndGet() == 0)
        {
            super.close();
            helper = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a very strange requirement to have multiple databases.  Could it really be talking about _tables_ instead.  I might take a step back and challenge the requirement.

Comment: You should be able to create a `DatabaseHelper` dynamically.  Does your posted code not work when you specify one database name and then another?

Comment: Requirement is valid.  Just tough to explain.  The app was coded for one event and now they want it to be able to handle multiple events so it is all the same data just a different event.  I can create them dynamically.  I'm just trying to figure out how to make it thread safe.  In other words the usageCounter wouldn't work correctly with multiple DBs.

Comment: Why not have some sort of event type field to help differentiate between event types in the same table?

Comment: You could have a `ConcurrentHashMap<String AtomicInteger>` and lookup the usage counter by the database name or something.

Comment: I thought about that way first but my only concern would be how big the database could become.  I have no control over the size so for efficiency, I would want separate DBs.

Comment: Yea.  I assumed I would need some sort of List to hold the usageCounter in.

Comment: I would really argue that separating out to multiple databases would _not_ give you better efficiency.  You are going to be limited by IO speed not by some thread limitation.  Smacks of premature optimization and complexity to me.

Comment: Yea.  I would also have to do a list for all my Daos too which could get quite complex.